# How can i bind jquery datepicker with angular text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have this datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinj/TAeNF/2/

Current has code like this

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I am using it like this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker />
<br/>
{{ date }}
```

My problem is i want to use it in multiple places and they can have different model like

`model=date1` , `model=date2`

Is there any way to make that generic so that it works on model whatever it is attached to rather than hard code

```
scope.date = date;
```

Comment: `data.title` is 2 way bound. so if you update modelto inside directive it will reflect on the data.title outside. What is the issue?

Comment: @PSL I was using date picker in that input box and i have seen that i start deleting something with keyboard then i can see the parent value gets updated but not on select of datepicker. i was using this datepicker http://jsfiddle.net/kevinj/TAeNF/2/

Comment: I just see it working perfectly fine in your example and here too http://plnkr.co/edit/FPFuTO?p=preview

Comment: @PSL sorry , i realised that there is issue with datepicker not assigning value to correct model but not scope. I have edited the question with more detail

Comment: Your question looks the same with a working jsfiddle. Please show us the issue in the demo.

Comment: @PSL That datepicker fiddle i have got from internet. There it uses `scope.date = date` now as i will be using my directive at many places and there will be different name for date. i want to know which thing i can write in jqdatepicker something like `scope.getfrominputmodel = date` so that it works

Comment: @PSL i have changed the questions

Comment: Ok now it is clear what you are trying to achieve, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ngModel controller to set the value instead of setting a scope variable inside default scoped directive. If you are updating any scope property and you want to make it reusable you should not use default scope option (when not mentioned defaults to current scope, same as scope:false), or if you are requiring ngModel then just make use of ngModel controller instance. In your case 3 key things are:-

```
//Set $viewvalue property of ngModel
ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
//Update the input with the ngmodel view value or in otherwords render it.
ngModelCtrl.$render();
//Update any bindings invoking digest cycle
scope.$apply();
```

Try:

```
datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    //Set viewvalue and apply it to update the input
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    //Update bindings
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sgr8gL5/)**